# Differentiate a kronecker product

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

Recently I want to pratice matrix calculus, and I face the following questions. I have a kronecker product and I don't know how to differentiate it. Could you please help me?
$$
\frac{\partial(\theta\theta^T\otimes I_{n*n})}{\partial\theta}
$$
where $\theta$ is a vector and $I_{n*n}$ is a identity matrix.

My thought is that
$$
\frac{\partial(\theta\theta^T\otimes I_{n*n})}{\partial\theta}=(I\otimes\theta+\theta\otimes I)\otimes I_{n*n}
$$
And is it right? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\t{\theta}\def\e{{\large e}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Unfortunately, you've picked a difficult practice problem because a matrix-by-vector gradient produces a third-order ***tensor*** which cannot be represented using standard matrix notation. However, the component-wise gradients are simply matrices, so let's calculate those.

First, recall that the gradient of a vector with respect to one of its own components is the corresponding cartesian basis vector, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\t = \sum_k\t_k\e_k \qiq \grad{\t}{\t_k} = \e_k \\
}$$
Applying this to your matrix-valued function yields
a set of ***matrix-valued*** gradients
$$\eqalign{
F\; &= \;\t\t^T\otimes I \\
\grad{F}{\t_k} &= \LR{\e_k\t^T+\t\e_k^T}\otimes I \\
}$$